# C# win installer, как запустить установку стороннего по

Tags: c#, windowsinstaller

Позволяет ли Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects запускать установку сторонних программ, от которых зависит текущий проект? Если да, то как?

Comment: Что значит "зависит"? Если вы используете Office Interop, значит ли что инсталлер должен скачать и установить офис целиком? Или что в вашем понимании "зависимость"?

Comment: @aepot ваш пример хорошо описывает то, что я хочу получить в идеале

Comment: Ну тогда универсального решения нет.